# iOS: How to determine whether three CGPoints lie in a straight line

Tags: algorithm

I have two given CGPoints A and B and one another CGPoint C as obtained from within touchesEnded event.
I want to determine whether the three points lie in a straight line for which I have used the below given formula:
For point A(x1, y1), B(x2, y2) and C(x3, y3)
x1(y2 - y3) + x2 (y3-y1) + x3(y1-y2) = 0
But the formula doesn't helpful at all.
is there any other way of determining collinearity of three points in iOS
Thanks
arnieterm

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can you determine a point is between two other points on a line segment?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/328107/how-can-you-determine-a-point-is-between-two-other-points-on-a-line-segment)

Comment: Duplicate question is for Python, however the math is the same (and even the code is almost the same).

Answer (score 1):

This is not really an iOS question, or even a programming question -- it's an algorithm question.

I'm not sure if the algorithm you were given is correct -- see the cross-product answer given in comments for what I think of as the correct answer.  In what way do you find your formula not helpful?  Here it is in code, btw. (code typed in browser, not checked):

```
CGPoint p1;
CGPoint p2;
CGPoint p3;
const float closeEnough = 0.00001;  // because floats rarely == 0

float v1 = p1.x * (p2.y - p3.y);
float v2 = p2.x * (p3.y - p1.y);
float v3 = p3.x * (p1.y - p2.y);

if (ABS(v1 + v2 + v3) < closeEnough)
{
    // your algorithm is true
}
```

Comment: This formula will only work when the three points are in straight line. In my case the user touch point does not appear exactly inline with start and end points.

Comment: If instead I attempt to find angle between these 3 points. Will it helps? The problem is user is tapping on a set of points laid out in a matrix form. Even if I consider the angle then what must be the range of angles needs to considered?