# Matlab - Failures of function to detect collisions between line segments and circle

Tags: matlab, line, geometry, line-segment

Many questions exist already covering how to detect collisions between a line segment and a circle.

In my code, I am using Matlab's `linecirc` function, then comparing the intersection points it returns with the ends of my line segments, to check that the points are within the line (linecirc assumes an infinite line, which I don't have/want).

Copying and adding some `sprintf` calls to the `linecirc` function shows that it is calculating points as intended. These seem to be being lost by my function.

My code is below:

```
function cutCount = getCutCountHex(R_g, centre)
clf;
cutCount = 0;

% Generate a hex grid
Dg = R_g*2;
L_b = 62;

range = L_b*8;

dx = Dg*cosd(30);
dy = 3*R_g;
xMax = ceil(range/dx); yMax = ceil(range/dy);
d1 = @(xc, yc) [dx*xc dy*yc];
d2 = @(xc, yc) [dx*(xc+0.5) dy*(yc+0.5)];

centres = zeros((xMax*yMax),2);
count = 1;

for yc = 0:yMax-1
    for xc = 0:xMax-1
        centres(count,:) = d1(xc, yc);
        count = count + 1;
        centres(count, :) = d2(xc, yc);
        count = count + 1;
    end
end

for i=1:size(centres,1)
    centres(i,:) = centres(i,:) - [xMax/2 * dx, yMax/2 * dy];
end

hold on
axis equal

% Get counter for intersected lines
[VertexX, VertexY] = voronoi(centres(:,1), centres(:,2));
numLines = size(VertexX, 2);
for lc = 1:numLines
    segStartPt = [VertexX(1,lc) VertexY(1,lc)];
    segEndPt = [VertexX(2,lc) VertexY(2,lc)];
    slope = (segEndPt(2) - segStartPt(2))/(segEndPt(1) - segStartPt(1));
    intercept = segEndPt(2) - (slope*segEndPt(1));
    testSlope = isinf(slope);
    if (testSlope(1)==1)
        % Pass the x-axis intercept instead
        intercept = segStartPt(1);
    end
    [xInterceptionPoints, yInterceptionPoints] = ...
        linecirc(slope, intercept, centre(1), centre(2), L_b);

    testArr = isnan(xInterceptionPoints);
    if (testArr(1) == 0) % Line intersects. Line segment may not.
        interceptionPoint1 = [xInterceptionPoints(1), yInterceptionPoints(1)];
        interceptionPoint2 = [xInterceptionPoints(2), yInterceptionPoints(2)];

        % Test if first intersection is on the line segment
        p1OnSeg = onSeg(segStartPt, segEndPt, interceptionPoint1);
        p2OnSeg = onSeg(segStartPt, segEndPt, interceptionPoint2);
        if (p1OnSeg == 1)
            cutCount = cutCount + 1;
            scatter(interceptionPoint1(1), interceptionPoint1(2), 60, 'MarkerFaceColor', 'r', 'MarkerEdgeColor', 'k');
        end

        % Test if second intersection point is on the line segment
        if (interceptionPoint1(1) ~= interceptionPoint2(1) || interceptionPoint1(2) ~= interceptionPoint2(2)) % Don't double count touching points
            if (p2OnSeg == 1)
                cutCount = cutCount + 1;
                scatter(interceptionPoint2(1), interceptionPoint2(2), 60, 'MarkerFaceColor', 'r', 'MarkerEdgeColor', 'k');
            end
        end
    end
end

% Plot circle

viscircles(centre, L_b, 'EdgeColor', 'b');
H = voronoi(centres(:,1), centres(:,2));
for i = 1:size(H)
    set(H(i), 'Color', 'g');
end
end

function boolVal = onSeg(segStart, segEnd, testPoint)
bvX = isBetweenOrEq(segStart(1), segEnd(1), testPoint(1));
bvY = isBetweenOrEq(segStart(2), segEnd(2), testPoint(2));
if (bvX == 1 && bvY == 1)
    boolVal = 1;
else
    boolVal = 0;
end
end

function boolVal = isBetweenOrEq(end1, end2, test)
    if ((test <= end1 && test >= end2) || (test >= end1 && test <= end2))
        boolVal = 1;
    else
        boolVal = 0;
    end
end
```

It creates a hexagonal grid, then calculates the number of crossings between a circle drawn with a fixed radius (62 in this case) and a specified centre.

The `scatter` calls show the locations that the function counts.
Implementing `sprintf` calls within the `if(p1OnSeg == 1)` block indicates that my function has chosen fictitious intersection points (although it then deals with them correctly)

```
if (interceptionPoint1(1) > -26 && interceptionPoint1(1) < -25)
                sprintf('p1 = [%f, %f]. Vx = [%f, %f], Vy = [%f, %f].\nxint = [%f, %f], yint = [%f, %f]',...
                    interceptionPoint1(1), interceptionPoint1(2), VertexX(1,lc), VertexX(2,lc), VertexY(1,lc), VertexY(2,lc),...
                    xInterceptionPoints(1), xInterceptionPoints(2), yInterceptionPoints(1), yInterceptionPoints(2))
            end
```

Outputs

```
p1 = [-25.980762, 0.000000]. Vx = [-25.980762, -25.980762], Vy = [-15.000000, 15.000000].
xint = [-25.980762, -25.980762], yint = [0.000000, 0.000000]
```

A picture shows the strange points.

[image]

Sorry for the very long question but - why are these being detected. They don't lie on the circle (displaying values within a `mylinecirc` function detects the intersections at around (-25, 55) and (-25, -55) or so (as an infinite line would expect).

Moving the circle can remove these points, but sometimes this leads to other problems with detection. What's the deal?

**Edit:** Rotating my grid pattern created by `[Vx, Vy] = voronoi(...)` and then removing points with very large values (ie those going close to infinity etc) appears to have fixed this problem. The removal of 'large' value points seems to be necessary to avoid NaN values appearing in 'slope' and 'intercept'. My guess is this is related to a possible slight inclination due to rotation, coupled with then overflow of the expected intercept.

Example code added is below. I also edited in Jan de Gier's code, but that made no difference to the problem and so is not changed in the question code.

```
%Rotate slightly
RotAngle = 8;
RotMat = [cosd(RotAngle), -sind(RotAngle); sind(RotAngle), cosd(RotAngle)];

for i=1:size(centres,1)
    centres(i,:) = centres(i,:) - [floor(xMax/2) * dx, floor(yMax/2) * dy]; %Translation
    centres(i,:) = ( RotMat * centres(i,:)' ); %Rotation
end


% Get counter for intersected lines
[VertexX, VertexY] = voronoi(centres(:,1), centres(:,2));

% Filter vertices
numLines = size(VertexX, 2);
newVx = [];
newVy = [];
for lc = 1:numLines
    testVec = [VertexX(:,lc) VertexY(:,lc)];
    if ~any(abs(testVec) > range*1.5)
        newVx = [newVx; VertexX(:,lc)'];
        newVy = [newVy; VertexY(:,lc)'];
    end
end
VertexX = newVx';
VertexY = newVy';
numLines = size(VertexX, 2);
```

Still appreciating answers or suggestions to clear up why this is/was occuring.
Example values that cause this are `getCutCountHex(30, [0,0])` and `...(35, [0,0])`

Answer (score 1):

I cant reproduce your problem, but the thing I did notice is that your onSeg() function might be wrong: it returns true if the testpoint lies in the rectangle with two of the four corner points being segStart and segEnd.

A function that returns true iff a point is on (or more accurate: close enough to) the line segment (segStart,segEnd) could be:

```
function boolVal = onSeg(segStart, segEnd, testPoint)

    tolerance = .5;

    AB = sqrt((segEnd(1)-segStart(1))*(segEnd(1)-segStart(1))+(segEnd(2)-segStart(2))*(segEnd(2)-segStart(2)));
    AP = sqrt((testPoint(1)-segEnd(1))*(testPoint(1)-segEnd(1))+(testPoint(2)-segEnd(2))*(testPoint(2)-segEnd(2)));
    PB = sqrt((segStart(1)-testPoint(1))*(segStart(1)-testPoint(1))+(segStart(2)-testPoint(2))*(segStart(2)-testPoint(2)));

    boolVal = abs(AB - (AP + PB)) < tolerance;

end
```

an approach that I found in one of the anwers here: [Find if point lays on line segment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7050186/find-if-point-lay-on-line-segment). I hope that solves your problem.

Comment: You're correct that this is a more accurate assessment of if a point is on a line segment, so +1, but since the values that are passed to this function are 'supposed' (although better to be safe than sorry, so changed to your function) to be points on an infinite line of the same intercept and gradient, if the point is within the rectangle it is also on the line

Comment: In terms of reproducing the problem, calling `cc = getCutCountHex(30, [0,0])` gives wrong answers, but `...(33, [0,0])` produces the 8 intersections that are visible on the figure