# Retrieving node/edge with mouse events

Tags: java, mouseevent, graphstream

I'm following the [official GraphStream tutorial](https://graphstream-project.org/doc/Tutorials/Graph-Visualisation/), and as the title suggest - I'm trying to get node's by clicking on it.

this is my code so far:

```java
import org.graphstream.graph.*;
import org.graphstream.graph.implementations.*;
    
public static void main(String args[]) {
    Graph graph = new MultiGraph("Tutorial 1");
    graph.setStrict(false);
    graph.setAutoCreate( true );

    graph.addNode("A").setAttribute("xy", 1, 1);
    graph.addNode("B").setAttribute("xy", 5, 5);
    graph.addNode("C").setAttribute("xy", 1, 8);

    graph.addEdge("AB", "A", "B");
    graph.addEdge("BC", "B", "C");
    graph.addEdge("CA", "C", "A");

    Viewer viewer = graph.display();
    viewer.disableAutoLayout();
}
```

Is there an efficient way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here is the solution I have found:

First I've written a new `MouseManager` to override the default one, and I've used the function `findNodeOrSpriteAt(int x, int y)` to "catch" the clicked node:

```java
public class CustomMouseManager implements MouseManager {

    protected View view;
    protected GraphicGraph graph;

    @Override
    public void init(GraphicGraph graph, View view) {
        this.graph = graph;
        this.view = view;
        view.addMouseListener(this);
        view.addMouseMotionListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void release() {
        view.removeMouseListener(this);
        view.removeMouseMotionListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        int x = e.getX();
        int y = e.getY();

        GraphicElement node = view.findNodeOrSpriteAt(x, y);

        if(node != null){
            System.out.println("Node " + node.getId() + ": (" + x + "," + y + ")");
        }
    }
    // here you should implement the rest of the MouseManager's methods (mouseDragged, mouseReleased, etc.)
```

After that, I've added the new custom MouseManager to my `Viewer` with `setMouseManager()`

```java
public static void main(String args[]) {
    Graph graph = new MultiGraph("Tutorial 1");
    graph.setStrict(false);
    graph.setAutoCreate( true );

    graph.addNode("A").setAttribute("xy", 1, 1);
    graph.addNode("B").setAttribute("xy", 5, 5);
    graph.addNode("C").setAttribute("xy", 1, 8);

    graph.addEdge("AB", "A", "B");
    graph.addEdge("BC", "B", "C");
    graph.addEdge("CA", "C", "A");

    Viewer viewer = graph.display();
    viewer.disableAutoLayout();
    viewer.getDefaultView().setMouseManager(new MyMouseManager());
}
```

this code works for nodes but I'm still not sure what is the correct way to get an edge by clicking on it.

However, a naive solution might be to get the mouse-click's coordinates and then iterate the nodes and [check if those coordinates are between 2 nodes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17692922/check-is-a-point-x-y-is-between-two-points-drawn-on-a-straight-line).

another (faster) solution is - attaching [sprites](https://graphstream-project.org/doc/Tutorials/Graph-Visualisation/) to the edges:

```java
Sprite s1;
s1.attachToEdge("AB");
```

By doing this, one can retrieve the edge's sprite with the function `findNodeOrSpriteAt(int x, int y)` that I've used to retrieve nodes.

Answer (score 0):

For nodes, simply implement a `ViewerListener` as in the official documentation:

https://graphstream-project.org/doc/Tutorials/Graph-Visualisation/

On OS X you might want to run with `-Dsun.java2d.uiScale=100%` or otherwise coordinates might be wrong

For the hover events, you'll need to add `viewer.getDefaultView().enableMouseOptions();`

```
public class Clicks implements ViewerListener {
    protected boolean loop = true;

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.setProperty("org.graphstream.ui", "swing");
        new Clicks();
    }
    public Clicks() {
        Graph graph = new SingleGraph("Clicks");
        Viewer viewer = graph.display();

        viewer.setCloseFramePolicy(Viewer.CloseFramePolicy.HIDE_ONLY);

        ViewerPipe fromViewer = viewer.newViewerPipe();
        fromViewer.addViewerListener(this);
        fromViewer.addSink(graph);
    
        while(loop) {
            fromViewer.pump();
        }
    }

    public void viewClosed(String id) {
        loop = false;
    }

    public void buttonPushed(String id) {
        System.out.println("Button pushed on node "+id);
    }

    public void buttonReleased(String id) {
        System.out.println("Button released on node "+id);
    }

    public void mouseOver(String id) {
        System.out.println("Need the Mouse Options to be activated");
    }

    public void mouseLeft(String id) {
        System.out.println("Need the Mouse Options to be activated");
    }
}
```