# How to determine if a point is in the edge/boundaries of a 2D triangle?

Tags: algorithm, math, geometry

I saw a lot of posts describing how to find if the point lies outside or inside. But I want to know if there's a way to know if the point is in the edge of the triangle.

The equation should have 4 parameters `(p,x,y,z)`, the point which I try to discover lies on the edge and three other points that create the triangle

When I saw on edge, I mean on any of the segments, given a triangle "on edge" is any of the lines that create it

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2049582/how-to-determine-if-a-point-is-in-a-2d-triangle

Comment: But that only determines if it's inside or outside the triangle, I want to know if the point is rigth in an edge

Comment: Write the equations of the sides. See if it makes them true. Or simpler: take slopes when it is connected to each vertex and see if any match.

Comment: Also, if you're thinking of sides as segments (not lines), check betweenness.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11907947/how-to-check-if-a-point-lies-on-a-line-between-2-other-points

Comment: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/rp0xnhzawy Maybe you need this.

Comment: @LearnHowToBeTransparent that's what I want to know, if the point I choose if one of those who conform the segment

Comment: How do you know if a point is on a segment? You need to determine if point is on either one of three segments.

Answer (score 2):

What does **on** the edge mean ?

Even if your end points and the point you pick are integers the equation of line is not. No point will ever be on the line to infinite precision (except for obvious cases)

It really only makes sense to say the point is within some small distance of the line. See [Shortest distance between a point and a line segment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/849211/shortest-distance-between-a-point-and-a-line-segment) for equations.

Answer (score 2):

When you calculate postition of the point relative to triangle edge with function from linked answer:

```
float sign (fPoint p1, fPoint p2, fPoint p3)
{
    return (p1.x - p3.x) * (p2.y - p3.y) - (p2.x - p3.x) * (p1.y - p3.y);
}
```

then **zero sign value** denotes that **point lies exactly on the edge**.

*(More exactly - on the line containing edge. Signs for two other edges show whether point is between vertices)*

If you need some tolerance level to compensate floating-point errors, just compare absolute "sign" value with triangle area.

```
DoubledTriangleArea = Abs(sign(v1, v2, v3)
if (Abs(sign(p, v1, v2)) / DoubledTriangleArea < SomeSmallValue)
    p lies near v1-v2 edge
```