# To determine if a point is on a line

Tags: java, android

i have been trying to determine if a point lies on a line. The line is drawn on a pdf document in android app using Pdftron.

I have been trying to solve this since 2 weeks, please help me out.

Following is the code

```
mPDFView.setDoc(doc);// doc is a PDF document.

mPDFView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {//mPDFView is a third party layout component created by Pdftron

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent arg1) {
        if(arg1.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
          //record the start time
            startTime = arg1.getEventTime();
            arg1.getX();
            arg1.getY();
        }
        else if(arg1.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
          //record the end time
            endTime = arg1.getEventTime();
        }
        if(endTime - startTime > 1000){
            xValue=arg1.getX();
            yValue=arg1.getY();
            int page_num = 1;
            try{
            for (PageIterator itr = doc.getPageIterator(); itr.hasNext();) {
                   System.out.println("Page " + (page_num++) + ": ");
               Page page = (Page) (itr.next());
                   int num_annots;
               num_annots = page.getNumAnnots();
               for (int i = 0; i < num_annots; ++i) {
                 Annot annot = page.getAnnot(i); 
                 if (annot.isValid() == false)
                    continue;
                 double[] bbox = annot.getRect().get();
                     double x1 = bbox[0];  
                 double y1 = bbox[1];
                 double x2 = bbox[2];
                 double y2 = bbox[3];                              
                 double slope_line = (y1-y2)/(x1-x2);
        boolean point_status = methodLineEquation(slope_line, xValue, yValue, x1, y1);
                }
              }
           }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
           }
        }
    return false;
                    }
   });

public boolean methodLineEquation(double slope,double newX,double newY,double x1,double y1){
            double y=newY;
        double x=newX;
            double result = (y - y1)-(slope*(x-x1));// Line Equation
            if(result==0){
               Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Point on line", 500).show();
                return true;
            }
            else{
               Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Point not on line",500).show();
                return false;
            }
 }
```

Note : Braces might not be proper as I have removed some unneccesary lines of code. Please ignore.

Comment: please fix your indentation, this is illegible.

Comment: What problem/error are you getting?

Comment: This [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/328107/how-can-you-determine-a-point-is-between-two-other-points-on-a-line-segment) should answer your needs.

Comment: Where are you having trouble? Is there an error? Does it have the wrong output?

Comment: It gives me wrong output, as all the co-ordinates are in double data type there is being a minute difference.