# Find point of intersection as well as the segment

Tags: python, shapely

I have two line paths (non straight lines) and I would like to determine at which segment they intersect. My first line consists of 97 points and the other line consists of 50 points and they intersect at one point. I will use a smaller data set below for simplicity.  I am able to find the intersections point using Shapely `intersection` method but I'm having a hard time finding the segment.

```
from shapely.geometry import *
a = [[1246.27886576,  397.92212558], [1257.07143932,  386.62625213], [1248.9911559 ,  364.85303935], [1243.15355998,  351.2073384 ], [1252.96611444,  345.8853271 ], [1259.99528981,  343.00414527]]

b = [ [1234.5260801 ,  364.17967993], [1243.18178589,  363.32934182], [1251.03950905,  360.78543246], [1256.76030287,  358.07463708], [1293.17663569,  365.07308725], [1311.17586247,  368.66783979]]

line1 = LineString(a)
line2 = LineString(b)
point = line1.intersection(line2)
## point is (1247.711909530379 361.8627307297313)
```

Then I have the following to find the line segment that has the intersection in "a"

```
for x in range(len(a)-1):
        line = LineString(a[x:x+2])
        if(point.within(line)):
            print(x)
```

The problem is that I am getting nothing. By looking visually at the point, I expect that the point would be between the third and fourth point. But the "point within" is returning false. I am suspecting the equality is lost due to decimal points.

Is there any way I can find the segment of intersection?

Comment: Your answer is here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21291725/determine-if-shapely-point-is-within-a-linestring-multilinestring. You need to use `line.distance(point) < 1e-8` within error threshold. Output looks like LINESTRING (1248.9911559 364.85303935, 1243.15355998 351.2073384)

Comment: The referred link helped me. Thank you