# Shapely within confusing the heck out of me

Tags: python, shapely

I'm having a lot of trouble with getting shapely points to actually snap on linestrings. This is really important to be able to construct a network graph from geospatial data for example. I would like to avoid using `shapely.ops.snap` as according to the docs this seems only to snap to line vertices. Instead I would like to use the linear referencing technique proposed in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24415806/coordinates-of-the-closest-points-of-two-geometries-in-shapely/24440122#24440122). For a simple point-in-linestring situation (see TEST2 below) this seems to work fine, and the `within` assertion evaluates to true. However, I can't seem to get it to work for a more complex linestring, even though matplotlib clearly shows the point to lie somewhere along the linestring.

```
from shapely.wkt import loads
from shapely.geometry import LineString, Point
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import geopandas

class Test:
    def __init__(self, point, line):
        self.point = point
        self.line = line
    def snap(self, point, line):
        snapped_point = line.interpolate(line.project(point))
        return snapped_point
    def test(self):
        snapped_point = self.snap(self.point, self.line)
        plt.close()
        fig = plt.figure()
        ax = plt.gca()
        geopandas.GeoDataFrame(geometry=[snapped_point]).plot(ax=ax)
        geopandas.GeoDataFrame(geometry=[ls]).plot(ax=ax)

        return snapped_point.within(self.line)
    def show(self):
        plt.show()

### TEST 1
point = loads('POINT (141508.3132070995 445104.7256057188)')
ls = loads('LINESTRING (141408.7699052179 445535.6376462562, 141420.9609999987 445491.5920000025, 141444.1930000001 445394.7640000023, 141465.3480000009 445299.004, 141486.3999999985 445202.0350000015, 141508.3209999985 445104.6910000004, 141529.2399999978 445006.3560000034, 141550.8399999999 444909.6550000002, 141572.6389999985 444811.9950000045, 141594.0459999999 444713.4210000001, 141614.9339999997 444616.2859999968)')
test1 = Test(point, ls)
print(test1.test())
test1.show()

### TEST 2
point = Point((0.5, 0.46))
ls = LineString([(0,0), (1,1), (2,2)])
test2 = Test(point, ls)
print(test2.test())
test2.show()
```

Why does the second linestring check evaluate to False? Shouldn't the `interpolate` and `project` methods be geometry independent?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Determine if Shapely point is within a LineString/MultiLineString](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21291725/determine-if-shapely-point-is-within-a-linestring-multilinestring)