# Click on marker and highlight underlying polyline

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, leaflet

I need to check if a polyline runs under a marker. The marker and polyline should have the same latLng at that point. The problem is that there are multiple markers on my map. I can't seem to figure out how I can get the right polylines selected.

Object of Marker/Polyline:

```
{  
    latLng:     Array with latLng's,  
    marker:     Leaflet marker/polyline layer object,  
    selected:   boolean  
}
```

Polylines that crosses a marker contains the same latlng point as the marker, but I can't get the right result. I think it's more a mathematical problem

Image for more info:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CABjB.png]

P.S. Sorry for my bad english

Comment: Take a look at turf.js.  It has simple geo-analysis tools.  If using plain javascript you could just loop over the geometry in the line layer group. Can you make a plunker.

Comment: Is it always the starting or ending point of the polyline that crosses the marker?

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
markerLatLng = marker.getLatLng()

for(var i = 0; i < latLng.length-1; i++){
    if (isBetween(latLng[i], latLng[i+1], markerLatLng)){
        // marker is between this line segment
        selected = true; //or do what you want to here 
    }
}    

def isBetween(a, b, c){
    crossproduct = (c.lng - a.lng) * (b.lat - a.lat) - (c.lat - a.lat) * (b.lng - a.lng);
    if(Math.abs(crossproduct) > epsilon) return false; //epsilon = 0 for integers, use small number operations on floating point coordinates

    dotproduct = (c.lat - a.lat) * (b.lat - a.lat) + (c.lng - a.lng)*(b.lng - a.lng);
    if(dotproduct < 0) return false;

    squaredlengthba = (b.lat - a.lat)*(b.lat - a.lat) + (b.lng - a.lng)*(b.lng - a.lng);
    if(dotproduct > squaredlengthba) return false;

    return true;
}
```

Note: Floating point arithmetic errors will give you grief here. Modify epsilon to increase the buffer around the line to which the marker is considered "on the line".

Adapted from this [answer by Cyrille Ka](https://stackoverflow.com/a/328122/2977944)