# Checking if vector passes through vertices

Tags: c++, math, vector, graphics, shader

I have been struggling with this problem for over a month, so I really need your help.

To further elaborate on the question :

The question is whether a vector called 'direction' that starts at a vertex called 'start' passes through the 'taget'.

You need to confirm the direction and distance.

I decided that using the dot product was impossible because I went through enough debugging.

1. The result is good when calculated directly, but why is the result different when executed in the shader?
2. The same thickness should be printed depending on the distance, but why does the thin line appear when the distance is far?
3. Do you have any good ideas even if it's not the way I use the rotation matrix?

These are three questions.
First of all, my situation is

1. drawing fSQ.
2. I want to check whether the direction of start passes through the target.
3. Compute in the pixel shader.
4. 1 is one pixel
5. The screen size is 1920*1080

   ```
    bool intersect(float2 target, float2 direction, float2 start) {

    bool intersecting = false;
    static const float thresholdX = 0.5 / SCREENWIDTH;
    static const float thresholdY = 0.5 / SCREENHEIGHT;

    if (direction.x == 0 && direction.y == 0);

    else {
        float2 startToTarget = target - start;
        float changedTargetPositionX = startToTarget.x * direction.x + startToTarget.y * direction.y;
        float changedTargetPositionY = startToTarget.x * (-direction.y) + startToTarget.y * direction.x;
        float rangeOfX = (direction.x * direction.x) + (direction.y * direction.y);

        if (changedTargetPositionX <= rangeOfX + thresholdX && changedTargetPositionX >= -thresholdX &&
            changedTargetPositionY <= thresholdY && changedTargetPositionY >= -thresholdY) {
            intersecting = true;
        }
    }

    return intersecting;
   ```

We use a rotation matrix to rotate a vector and then check the difference between the two vectors, which works in most cases, but fails for very small pixels.

For example

`start = (15,0) direction= (10,0) taget = (10,0)`

In this case, the intersect function should return false, but it returns true.

But if the pixel difference is bigger then it works fine.
and

```
#define MAX = 5;
float2 points[MAX*MAX];
for (float fi = 1; fi < MAX; fi++)
    for (float fj = 1; fj < MAX; fj++)
        points[(int)(fi * MAX + fj)] = float2(fi / MAX , fj / MAX);

for(uint ni=0; ni < MAX*MAX;ni++)
    for(uint nj=3; nj < MAX*MAX; nj++)
        if (intersect(uv,  points[nj]- points[ni], points[ni])) {

            color = float4(1, 0, 0, 1);
            return color;
        }
return float4(0, 0, 0, 1);
```

When debugging like this, the line becomes thinner depending on the distance.
All the lines should have the same thickness, but I don't know why.

This is the result of running the debugging code:

[image: This is the result of running the debugging code.]

We look forward to your reply.
thank you

Comment: For one, you definitely need a [example] there.

Comment: Then • why don't you normalize the direction before applying the rotation matrix? • you're adding two values of different units -- rangeOfX has the unit of (squared unit) but thresholdX has the unit of (unit), which doesn't make sense • explain how you derive the math and what you want to compute exactly. • besides, `#define MAX = 5 ;` obviously won't work with the rest of the code.

Comment: If normalized, only the direction of the vector remains and information on the distance is deleted, so normalization is not possible.
Assuming that the starting point and the target are between the same 'x' axis, the intersect function should return false if the vector starting from the starting point is less than the distance to the x-axis.

Comment: Okay so you want to check if the point at coordinate `target` lies on the line segment from point `start` to point `start+direction`, with tolerance half a pixel?

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly? If you just want to draw a line then use one of the [line drawing algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_drawing_algorithm) instead. Unless the width is sufficiently large (e.g. 3 pixel), the noise will be larger than the exact thickness of the line.

Comment: Even if you can't correctly implement the cross product method, try the distance method first? [python - How can you determine a point is between two other points on a line segment? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/328107/how-can-you-determine-a-point-is-between-two-other-points-on-a-line-segment/328193#328193)

Comment: To be precise, I want to find out the "direction" that starts with "start", that is, whether the vector passes through the target.
I know how to compare distances, just not using the sqrt () function, rangeOfX means distance.

Comment: okay so you want to check if the point at coordinate target lies on the line segment from point start to point start+direction, with tolerance half a pixel? this is Right

Comment: python --How can you determine a point is between two other points on a line segment? --Stack Overflow tried to connect, but there is no way to use it.
In addition, since it is two-dimensional, it is not necessary to use the outer product, and because it is the inner product or the angle, the angle increases as the distance increases, and the error becomes larger.