# Eigen: way to check if point is on a segment?

Tags: c++, eigen, eigen3

I need to know if a point lies on a segment in 2d.

I already solved that issue using Boost and intersects between a point and a segment.

#### Question

is it possible to use the Eigen library **only**?

#### Why:

I am currently in the middle of an algorithm that uses Eigen, and I don't want to copy my points again and again in a loop to a Boost geometry construct to check for this.
**This is what I currently do and it works. But it adds a dependency.**

This is a contrived code:

```
using Line2 = Eigen::Hyperplane <double, 2>;
using Vec2 = Eigen::Vector2d;
Vec2 a( 0, 0 );
Vec2 b( 1, 1 );

Vec2 d(70, 100); 

Line2 ab = Line2::Through( a, b );

auto res = ab.normal();

auto projection_point = ab.projection(d); <- that projection point is not on the segment ab
//.. here I test with Boost and loop again if necessary
```

if there is no alternative I will keep doing it the way I do, but I am sure someone knows better out there.

I don't want to write the function myself (otherwise, I prefer to keep using Boost). I just want to rely on Eigen.

Thanks

Comment: It is possible without any libraries...

Comment: Yes, but I have to write it, and I don't want that. I want to minimize my "fingerprint" on that codebase. I could have copy/pasted https://lucidar.me/en/mathematics/check-if-a-point-belongs-on-a-line-segment/ as an example, but I don't want to maintain/explain it after I'm done with that work

Comment: Well Eigen is not a geometry library. You can formulate the problem in terms of an [overconstrained linear system](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__LeastSquares.html) but it is hardly any simpler or less code than a straightforward solution.

Comment: For checking if a point is "on" a Hyperplane, you can check if the absolute distance is below a threshold: https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1Hyperplane.html#a6d7e330896982be88d4e6cf8e9365687 -- for checking if `X` is on a segment between points `A` and `B`, check if `(A-X).norm() + (X-B).norm() < (A-B).norm() + tolerance`

Answer (score 1):

I suggest checking the distance of the point and its projection onto the line against an epsilon. Plus a check against the distance from origin, plus a check (via a dot product) that the point lies in the correct direction from the origin.

Eigen has a parameterized line type for this. It isn't a line segment but an origin plus direction vector. So the maximum distance from the origin has to be computed and stored separately.

```
using PLine2d = Eigen::ParameterizedLine<double, 2>;
Eigen::Vector2d a = ..., b = ..., d = ...;
PLine2d line = Pline2d::Through(a, b);
double sqrlength = (b - a).squaredNorm();
Eigen::Vector2d projection = line.projection(d);
Eigen::Vector2d fromOrigin = projection - line.origin();
bool isOnLineSegment = projection.isApprox(d) && 
                       fromOrigin.squaredNorm() <= sqrlength &&
                       fromOrigin.dot(line.direction()) >= 0.f;
```

I haven't counted operations but there is a good chance that the [code you linked](https://lucidar.me/en/mathematics/check-if-a-point-belongs-on-a-line-segment/) is shorter and faster when implemented in Eigen. Cross and dot products are readily available, after all.

Replace `squaredNorm()` with `stableNorm()` if desired. In 2D `hypotNorm()` would also work well.

A potential issue is [`isApprox()`](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1DenseBase.html#ae8443357b808cd393be1b51974213f9c) which, as the documentations states, fails close to zero. Therefore depending on your data, an extended check may be necessary such as

`(projection.isApprox(d) || (d.isZero() && projection.isZero()))`

All have tuneable epsilon parameters.

Comment: Thanks Homer, this is exactly what I was after

Comment: This doesn't [quite work](https://godbolt.org/z/b7sMKTGY5).

Comment: Yes, even with the modification, it still gives me a wrong answer

Comment: @Kroma You're right, the answer was wrong. We also have to check that the projected point is not before the starting point on the line

Comment: There are several ways to check this "between" condition, I think the simplest one is dot(a-c,b-c)<=0 but I might be wrong. There is a [list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/328107/how-can-you-determine-a-point-is-between-two-other-points-on-a-line-segment) of methods by the way.